# Starting the Google calendar sync in Samsung Galaxy S Duos

Tags: sync, google-calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have Samsung Galaxy S Duos and had a issue of calendar sync. While trying to clear data, I mistakenly force-stopped the Google Calendar Sync app. Now, the calendar sync is not working. It gives an error: `Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly.`

How do I start the Google Calendar Sync app again?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone, and starting the sync again?

Comment: yes. but didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install the Google Calendar from the Market.

[Source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/XmjZwWzjFLw).

Comment: i already had the Google calendar app installed earlier. i uninstall and re installed the Google calendar app but the same error pops up.. :(

Comment: @Rifky After you uninstall, and re-install it, make sure you clear the data before you start the sync. `Settings > Applications > All > Calendar (or calendar storage) > Clear data`.

Comment: :-( no success. still the same error when trying to sync in Settings->Account and Sync. no calenders are listed in Google calendar app.

Comment: now it started syncing. we need to clear the cache before we re install the google calendar app.

Comment: @Rifky Glad it finally worked for you. :) So `Clear data` was all you had to do? Or did you do something else?

Comment: i uninstalled the Google Calendar app first, then cleared data. then it started working. after that i installed Google Calnedar app and that's also syncing fine. :-)